# PHP regex fetch part of string?

Tags: php, string

Consider we have a string (which is MySQL Error message) as following:

> Data truncated for column 'sam_office_balance' at row 1

Now I need the part in single quotes as:

> Sam Office Balance

```
$errorMessage = "Data truncated for column 'sam_office_balance' at row 1";
// do smthing
echo $message; //  Should print "Sam Office Balance"
```

**What could be the best possible way to this?**

My Solution

```
private function sqlErrorMessage($message){

      //My SQL DataType Error
      $error_string_1 = "Data truncated for column '";
      $error_string_2 = "' at row";
      $pos_error_string_1 = strpos($message, $error_string_1);
      $pos_error_string_2 = strpos($message, $error_string_2);
      if(gettype($pos_error_string_1) != "boolean" && gettype($pos_error_string_2) != "boolean"){
          $pos_error_string_1 += strlen($error_string_1);
          $errorColumn = substr($message, $pos_error_string_1, $pos_error_string_2 - $pos_error_string_1);
          $errorMessage = $this->uc_w($errorColumn)." has invalid data.";
          return $errorMessage;
      }

      return $message;
    }
```

> **Language: PHP**
>
> **Technique:** *Anything with minimum lines of code.*

Comment: Say what? I can't understand anything

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: @Andreas I need the part of string i.e. 'sam_office_balance'.

Comment: @Gerriet Tried to find \' and then trim off un-required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$errorMessage = "Data truncated for column 'sam_office_balance' at row 1";
$pattern = "/'([^']+)'/";
$error = preg_match($pattern, $errorMessage, $matches);
echo($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strpos` and `strrpos` functions to find positions of first and the last occurence of `'`.

```
$string = "Data truncated for column 'sam_office_balance' at row 1";
$firstQuotePos = strpos($string, "'");
$lastQuotePos = strrpos($string, "'");
$column = substr($string, $firstQuotePos + 1, $lastQuotePos - $firstQuotePos - 1);

echo $column;
```

This code will output:

```
sam_office_balance
```

Then you can replace `_` by  (`str_replace` function) and make first letters uppercase (`ucwords` function).

```
echo ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', $column));
```

The above code will return you:

```
Sam Office Balance
```

If you want to have the maximum short code you can write just:

```
echo ucwords(str_replace('_', ' ', substr($string, strpos($string, "'") + 1, strrpos($string, "'") - strpos($string, "'") - 1)));
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped a lot. What if the string does not have 'Data truncated for column' or it has another single quote?

Comment: The above code catches content between first and last occurrence of `'`, so it's not matter what text will be in it.